# How can I stop react's router private route from redirecting to login page on refresh?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

PrivateRoute.js

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';

const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
    const { loading, isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  
    if (loading) return <Spinner />
    if (!isAuthenticated) return <Navigate to='/login' />
    return children;
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { loadUser } from './reducers/authSlice';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import Products from './screens/Products';
import Product from './screens/Product';
import Navigator from './components/layout/Navigator';
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer';
import Signup from './screens/Signup';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Dashboard from './screens/Dashboard';
import Settings from './screens/Settings';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';
import Store from './screens/Store';
import CreateOrUpdateStore from './screens/CreateOrUpdateStore';
import AddProduct from './screens/AddProduct';
import UpdateProduct from './screens/UpdateProduct';

const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
if (token) {
  setAuthToken(token); 
}

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated && token) {
      dispatch(loadUser());
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navigator />
      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="/products/:id" element={<Product />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<PrivateRoute><Dashboard /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/settings" element={<PrivateRoute><Settings /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/store" element={<PrivateRoute><Store /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/create-store" element={<PrivateRoute><CreateOrUpdateStore /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/update-store" element={<PrivateRoute><CreateOrUpdateStore /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/add-product" element={<PrivateRoute ><AddProduct /></PrivateRoute>} />
          <Route path="/update-product/:id" element={<PrivateRoute><UpdateProduct /></PrivateRoute>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import InputField from '../components/layout/InputField';
import Button from '../components/layout/Button';
import { faEnvelope, faUserCircle, faLock, faArrowRightToBracket } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { loginUser, clearMessages } from '../reducers/authSlice';
import FormAlert from '../components/layout/FormAlert';
import Spinner from '../components/layout/Spinner';

const Login = () => {
    const [ formData, setFormData ] = useState({
        email:'',
        password:''
    });

    const { email, password } = formData;

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { errors, message, loading, isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(clearMessages());
    },[dispatch]);

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const getError = (name) => {
        const findError = errors.filter(error => error.param === name);
        if (findError.length > 0) {
            const error = errors.find(error => error.param === name);
            return error;
        }
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = { email, password };
        dispatch(loginUser(data));
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(clearMessages());
        },3000);
    }

    if (loading) return <Spinner />

    if (isAuthenticated) return <Navigate to="/dashboard" />
    
    return (
        <form onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon style={{ backgroundColor: 'inherit', color: '#2596be', marginTop: '20px' }} size='8x' icon={faUserCircle} />
            {JSON.stringify(message) !== '{}' ? (<FormAlert alert={message} />) : ''}
            <InputField type='text' label='Email' name='email' value={email} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('email')} icon={faEnvelope} />
            <InputField type='password' label='Password' name='password' value={password} changeHandler={onChange} error={getError('password')} icon={faLock} />
            <Button text='LOGIN' loading={loading} icon={faArrowRightToBracket} />
        </form>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

authSlice.js

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { authAPI } from '../services/authAPI';

// Function for logging in user
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/loginUserStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.loginUser(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for loading user data
export const loadUser = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/loadUserStatus",
    async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.loadUser();
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for signing up a user
export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/signupUserStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.signupUser(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for verifying user accounts after sign up
export const verifyUser = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/verifyUserStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.verifyUser(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for resending otp
export const resendOtp = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/resendOtpStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.resendOtp(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for resending otp
export const retrievePassword = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/retrievePasswordStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.retrievePassword(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for generating authentication token when reseting forgotten password
export const generateToken = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/generateTokenStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.generateToken(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for creating new password
export const createNewPassword = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/createNewPasswordStatus",
    async (token, data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.createNewPassword(token, data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for updating user profile
export const updateAccount = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/updateAccountStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.editAccount(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for changing the logged in user password
export const changePassword = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/changePasswordStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.changePassword(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
);

// Function for uploading user profile picture
export const photoUpload = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/uploadPhotoStatus",
    async (data, { rejectWithValue }) => {
        try {
            const response = await authAPI.uploadPicture(data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
        }
    }
)

// The initial state of the reducer
const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    isAuthenticated: false,
    loading: false,
    message: {},
    errors: [],
    user: null,
    passwordResetToken: '',
    accountUpdating: false,
    passwordChangeLoading: false,
    photoUploadMessage: {},
    photoUploadLoading: false
};

// The auth slice
export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        clearMessages: (state) => {
            state.message = {};
            state.errors = [];
            state.photoUploadMessage = {};
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.token = localStorage.removeItem("token");
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
            state.user = null;
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(loginUser.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.user = null;
            state.message = {};
            state.errors = [];
            state.loading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(loginUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            if (payload.status === 'created') {
                state.message = payload;
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem("token", payload.data);
            }
            state.loading = false;
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(loginUser.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            if (payload.errors.length === 1) {
                state.message = payload.errors[0];
            } else {
                state.errors = payload.errors;
            }
            state.loading = false;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
        });
        builder.addCase(loadUser.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.errors = [];
            state.message = {};
            state.loading = true;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
        });
        builder.addCase(loadUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.user = payload.data;
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
            state.loading = false;
        });
        builder.addCase(loadUser.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.message = payload;
            state.user = null;
        });
        builder.addCase(signupUser.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.message = {};
            state.user = null;
            state.errors = [];
            state.loading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(signupUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.message = payload;
            state.user = { phonenumber: payload.data };
        });
        builder.addCase(signupUser.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            if (payload.errors.length === 1) {
                state.message = payload.errors[0];
            } else {
                state.errors = payload.errors;
            }
        });
        builder.addCase(verifyUser.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.message = {};
            state.errors = [];
            state.loading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(verifyUser.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.user = null;
            state.message = payload;
            state.loading = false;
        });
        builder.addCase(verifyUser.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.message = payload.errors[0];
            state.loading = false;
        });
        builder.addCase(resendOtp.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.message = {};
            state.loading = true;
            state.errors = [];
        });
        builder.addCase(resendOtp.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.message = payload;
        });
        builder.addCase(resendOtp.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.message = payload.errors[0];
        });
        builder.addCase(retrievePassword.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.message = {};
            state.loading = true;
            state.errors = [];
        });
        builder.addCase(retrievePassword.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.message = payload;
        });
        builder.addCase(retrievePassword.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.errors = payload.errors;
        });
        builder.addCase(generateToken.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.message = {};
            state.passwordResetToken = '';
            state.loading = true;
            state.errors = [];
        });
        builder.addCase(generateToken.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.passwordResetToken = payload.data;
        });
        builder.addCase(generateToken.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.errors = payload.errors;
        });
        builder.addCase(createNewPassword.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.message = {};
            state.loading = true;
            state.errors = [];
        });
        builder.addCase(createNewPassword.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.message = payload;
        });
        builder.addCase(createNewPassword.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.errors.push(payload);
        });
        builder.addCase(updateAccount.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.accountUpdating = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(updateAccount.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.accountUpdating = false;
            state.user = payload.data;
            const { data, ...rest } = payload;
            state.message = rest;
        });
        builder.addCase(updateAccount.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.accountUpdating = false;
            if (payload.errors && payload.errors.length > 0) {
                state.errors = payload.errors;
            } else {
                state.message = payload;
            }
        });
        builder.addCase(changePassword.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.passwordChangeLoading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(changePassword.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.passwordChangeLoading = false;
            state.message = payload;
        });
        builder.addCase(changePassword.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.passwordChangeLoading = false;
            if (payload.errors) {
                state.errors = payload.errors;
            } else {
                state.message = payload;
            }
        });
        builder.addCase(photoUpload.pending, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.photoUploadLoading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(photoUpload.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.photoUploadLoading = false;
            const { data, ...rest } = payload;
            state.photoUploadMessage = rest;
            state.user = data;
        });
        builder.addCase(photoUpload.rejected, (state, { payload }) => {
            state.photoUploadLoading = false;
            state.photoUploadMessage = payload;
        });
    }
});

export const { clearMessages, logout } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

I tried creating a private route and preventing the loadUser action from running on refresh if the user is already logged in by creating a condition on the App.js; but this method still prove to be ineffective in solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `loading` state that is initially true so that the `useEffect` in `App` has a chance to run and check the auth status prior to the `PrivateRoute` component checking the `isAuthenticated` state and redirecting. You may also want to initialize `isAuthenticated` to true of there was a persisted token in localStorage.

authSlice.js

```js
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
  isAuthenticated: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
  loading: true,
  message: {},
  errors: [],
  user: null,
  passwordResetToken: '',
  accountUpdating: false,
  passwordChangeLoading: false,
  photoUploadMessage: {},
  photoUploadLoading: false
};
```

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { loading, isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  
  if (loading) return <Spinner />;
  if (!isAuthenticated) return <Navigate to='/login' />;
  return children;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drew Reese. Your solution worked perfectly fine for me. My app indeed did not have enough time to check the auth state; thus redirecting me to the login page. Setting the loading to true kept my app loading conyinously. So I falsified the initial state to false, but I modified the isAuthenticated state to true. But it works perfectly fine now after I modified it using your suggestions. Thank you once more.